# How can I print list pdf file with name them in column excel?

Tags: excel, printing, export-to-excel, software-design

[image]

I want to print the list pdf file which it have name in 1 column of excel .

I don't want to hold the button Ctrl and find name of it one by one in column of excel and choose those file . Because may be have a lot of file . Find one by one take a lot of time.

For example with the image above.

**What software can support for me do this ? Or have to I do any thing to done this problem ???**.

Thank you for read my post !!!

Comment: I've found [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-print-a-pdf-in-excel-vba.908121/#post-4374225). If it works, you might define your range containing the addresses, use a For-Next cycle to pick each cell of the said range and then run the properly edited subroutine.

Comment: I have tried using their code with just entering a specific filename, not using For-Next to get multiple filenames. But it reported an error like this. Can you help me see this error?

Comment: This is my code: 

If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    PrintPDF = False
Else
    PrintPDF = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
 
Sub PrintSpecificPDF()
'opens the specified pdf and prints it using the default printer
'note that it uses the default PDF program and leaves it open

Dim strPth As String, strFile As String

strPth = "D:\PDF\"
strFile = "B01611.pdf"
 
If Not PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
    MsgBox "Printing failed"
End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
 
Public Function PrintPDF(xlHwnd As Long, FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim X As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    X = ShellExecute(xlHwnd, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 3)
    
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        PrintPDF = False
    Else
        PrintPDF = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
 
Sub PrintSpecificPDF()
    'opens the specified pdf and prints it using the default printer
    'note that it uses the default PDF program and leaves it open
    
    Dim strPth As String, strFile As String
    Dim rngList As Range, rngTarget As Range
    
    
    Set rngList = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    strPth = "D:\PDF\"
    
    For Each rngTarget In rngList
        
        strFile = rngTarget.Value & ".pdf"
         
        If Not PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
            MsgBox "Printing failed"
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I've taken this [code](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-print-a-pdf-in-excel-vba.908121/#post-4374225) and slightly modified it according to your case.